# Creating sites and Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, sub-site

How many sites can be created at a site collection level?

My friend and I are trying to figure out how SharePoint works. I am the site admin and gave exclusive rights to him so that he can do whatever I am able to do on the site.

I have created a top level site. Is it possible he can also create his own sites at a site collection level?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum recommended number of sites and subsites in a site collection is 250,000 sites.

However, creating too many sites below a top-level site in a site collection might affect performance and usability.  Microsoft recommends staying below 2,000 subsites per site collection.

For your second question, he can create his own site at a same site collection, but this new site will be a subsite. If he wants to have a independent site, I would suggest your friend create another site collection in SharePoint admin center.

Comment: How many TOP LEVEL SITES can possibly be created in a particular SharePoint admin center? Not under/below the main site ,but as a new top level site?

Comment: We can created 500,000 Site collections per organization. (But this Not including the OneDrive for Business site collections created for each licensed user) Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits

Answer (score 1):

According to the current [SharePoint Online Limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits) guidance, an organization can have up to 500,000 site collections.  This does not include the per licensed user One Drive for Business site collections.  Technically, these limits vary by plan type, but 500,000 is the limit on site collections for all plan types discussed in the document.

BTW, if I'm answering your question correctly, the confusion of previous answers is because you've used the terminology a bit incorrectly, though that's understandable if you're just figuring out SharePoint. The question should be: How many site collections per tenant (or organization)?

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback on his answer, you may find this documentation useful - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/plan-sites-and-site-collections